# php retrieve url components from foreign site for validation

Tags: php, url

I want to check the validity of a company number using a site which produces results only when a registered number is entered. 
There are 2 ways I think are possible:
1. After entering a valid number in the url the url i am redirected to contains 4 zero's which I might be able to target. I don't know if this is possible though seeing as I am redirected to another page (on the same website on which I am checking)
2. After entering a valid number the site shows extra data in a div. Otherwise the page is blank.

My problem lies in trying to get the page content or changed url. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish to get the url of the site with PHP. Use this:

```
<?php $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; }
```

Now to check the $url if it contains a string you can do it with this:

```
<?php 
     if (false !== strpos($url,'0000')) { 
     //CODE HERE
     }
?>
```